# Increasing net of projections in von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In $B(H)$, there exists an increasing sequence of finite rank projections convergent to the identity in SOT.

Is there an analogous statement for a  von Neumann algebra $M\subseteq B(H)$?

Comment: What do you want the analogue of "finite rank" to be?

Comment: Maybe the same in the usual sense of having finite dimensional range? That would be the best.

Comment: That is not intrinsic to a von Neumann algebra--a projection that is finite rank in one representation can be infinite rank in another.  For a really simple example, you could just take the subalgebra $\mathbb{C}$ of $B(H)$.

Comment: I see. I will edit my question and say that there's  a fixed representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $M$ need not contain any nonzero finite rank projections.  For a really simple example, $M$ could consist of only the scalar multiples of the identity.  Or, if $H=L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $M$ could be $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, which contains no nonzero finite rank operators since Lebesgue measure is atomless.

Comment: Is there a reasonable way to modify the meaning of finiteness here to get the desired analogue? I ask this because I came across the notion of $finite$ projections which may or may not be the right analogue for finite rank.

Comment: There is a notion of finite projections which is more versatile but a von Neumann algebra need not have many of them.  For instance, in a type III factor, no nonzero projection is finite.

Comment: In what I'm looking at, the von Neumann algebra has a faithful normal tracial state. Is that special enough?

Comment: That actually implies that *all* projections are finite.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I fail to see how that helps. However, in that setting, is there then an analogue to the statement above?

Comment: Well, the identity itself is a finite projection then, so the statement is trivial.

Comment: Ah, okay that was a dumb question.